# Why does class initializer get called when calling method is not run?

Tags: java, static-methods, static-initialization

I have a class in a protected/locked jar file that I have to *unlock* before I can use any of its classes. The class extends a class from java standard library:

```
ProtectedClass extends UnprotectedClass
```

In my unprotected code, I have the following method:

```
public static void xyz() {
    ProtectedClass object = getObjectSomehow();
    object.objectMethod();
    System.out.println(object.methodFromSuperclass());
    //System.out.println(((UnprotectedClass) object).methodFromSuperclass());
}
```

When I unlock the jar and then call `xyz()`, it does what it should.

But when I uncomment the commented out line which casts the object to its superclass before calling the superclass method, I get an `ExceptionInInitializerError` because the `<clinit>` of `ProtectedClass` has been run before I unlocked the jar. The same happens when I give `object` from `xyz()` to another method which parameter type is the superclass.

Why? Why does it depend on what I do in a method if a class initializer gets called ways before the method is invoked?

Comment: where is `clinit` in your code?

Comment: What do you mean by **unlocked the jar**?

Comment: `clinit` is nowhere in my code, I think it is the class initializer of `ProtectedClass` in the protected jar. **Unlocked the jar**: The jar is encrypted. *Unlocking* means that I call a method from it which adds a module to the JVM that decrypts the jar's contents before loading classes from it.

Comment: The class initializers of both `ProtectedClass` and `UnprotectedClass` run at some point during the running of the method `getObjectSomehow()`. The cast in the expression `((UnprotectedClass) object).methodFromSuperclass()` is completely unnecessary and means exactly the same as `object.methodFromSuperclass()`. `ExceptionInInitializerError` means that *some* initializer somewhere (not necessarily in the classes you're thinking of - it could, for example, be an inner class) has thrown *some* exception. Hopefully these pointers can help you investigate.

Comment: The only thing I change is removing the `//` from my example. Unfortunately the stack trace points exactly to the `<clinit>` from `ProtectedClass` and the error message yells "Moron, do not call `ProtectedClass.<clinit>` before unlocking!". If it *would be* called at `getObjectSomehow()`, it would work -- when that is called, the jar already is unlocked.